# PostgreSQL dblink with named connections

Tags: postgresql, session, connection, dblink

[**`dblink`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/contrib-dblink.html) does not seem to work when I use a named connection to a remote server or an unnamed connection and disconnect. It works fine if I use an unnamed connection with a connection string in dblink(). It appears to connect fine, but my connection is not available when I try to use it. Any ideas on how to get this working with named connections?

#### Unnamed with connstr Works Fine:

```
SELECT testtable.*
FROM   dblink('dbname=testdb port=5432 host=192.168.1.1 user=usr password=pw'
             ,'SELECT * FROM testtable')
AS     testtable(testtable_id integer, testtable_name text);
```

Returns: Two columns as expected.

#### Named Does not Work:

Connect:

```
SELECT dblink_connect('myconn'
           ,'dbname=testdb port=5432 host=192.168.1.1 user=usr password=pw');
```

Returns: "OK"

Query:

```
SELECT testtable.* FROM dblink('myconn', 'SELECT * FROM testtable')
AS     testtable(testtable_id integer, testtable_name text);
```

Returns:

```
ERROR:  could not establish connection
DETAIL:  missing "=" after "myconn" in connection info string

********** Error **********

ERROR: could not establish connection
SQL state: 08001
Detail: missing "=" after "myconn" in connection info string
```

Disconnect:

```
SELECT dblink_disconnect('myconn');
```

Returns:

```
ERROR:  connection "myconn" not available

********** Error **********

ERROR: connection "myconn" not available
SQL state: 08003
```

#### Unnamed with _connect and _disconnect Does not Work:

Connect:

```
SELECT dblink_connect('dbname=testdb port=5432 host=192.168.1.1
                                               user=usr password=pw');
```

Returns: "OK"

Query:

```
SELECT testtable.* FROM dblink('SELECT * FROM testtable')
AS testtable(testtable_id integer, testtable_name text);
```

Returns:

```
ERROR:  connection not available

********** Error **********

ERROR: connection not available
SQL state: 08003
```

Disconnect:

```
SELECT dblink_disconnect();
```

Returns:

```
ERROR:  connection not available

********** Error **********

ERROR: connection not available
SQL state: 08003
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a working setup with unnamed connections.

What you call "**Unnamed**" in your question, actually has a name parameter in it. You are confusing the two variants there. Try that without `'myconn'`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   dblink('SELECT * FROM testtable'
        ) AS testtable (testtable_id integer, testtable_name text);
```

And remember that establishing the connection and using it has to happen in the *same session*.

---

But I honestly cannot find what's wrong with your **named connection**. I have run a few tests and everything looks correct. I tested with PostgreSQL 9.1.

The error message implies that dblink expects a `connstr`. That only happens if the first parameter does not match any `connname` in existence In short: the connection `'myconn'` is not found -  which makes me suspect that you are not calling `dblink()` in the **same session** as `dblink_connect()`.

Comment: I removed 'myconn' from the Unnamed section.  I did not mean to include that.

Comment: Thanks. The session appears to be the issue. Running the queries in different windows in pgAdmin appears to treat each window as a separate session.  Running the queries in the same window one after the other is working.

Comment: @bendiy: Yes, in pgAdmin every SQL editor window runs a separate session. Temporary tables or dblink connections are only visible in the same window (session).